# Show for $X_0,X_1,...$ RV that $X_n\to^p X_0$ iff $\max_{k=1,...,d}\vert X_{n,k}-X_{0,k}\vert \to^p 0$ iff $\sum_{k=1}^d(X_{n,k}-X_{0,k})^2\to^p 0$

Tags: probability, solution-verification

> Show for $X_0,X_1,...$ $\mathbb{R}^d$ random vectors on the same probability space, that $X_n\to^p X_0$ if and only if $\max_{k=1,...,d}\vert X_{n,k}-X_{0,k}\vert \to^p 0$ if and only if $\sum_{k=1}^d(X_{n,k}-X_{0,k})^2\to^p 0$

$\vert X_{n,k}-X_{0,k}\vert$ is the kth coordinate distances of $X_n$ and $X_0$

I have this continuous mapping theorem which says if $g$ is a continuous real function and $X_n\to^p X$ then $g(X_n)\to^p g(X)$.

I want to prove them as $1\to 2\to 3\to 1$:

**1**. Assume $X_n\to^p X_0$

Let $\epsilon >0$

Then $P(\vert X_n-X_0\vert >\epsilon)\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$

I assumed $\vert X_n-X_0\vert$ is the same as euclidean distance, in which case I can use that $\vert X_{n,k} -X_{0,k}\vert\leq \vert X_n-X_0\vert$ for any $k=1,...,d$

And thus $\max_{k=1,...,d}\vert X_{n,k}-X_{0,k}\vert\leq \vert X_n-X_0\vert$

Then $P(\vert X_n-X_0\vert>\epsilon)\geq P(\max_{k=1,..,d} \vert X_{n,k}-X_{0,k}\vert>\epsilon)$

Then by squeeze theorem since $P(\vert X_n-X_0\vert>\epsilon)\to 0$, $P(\max_{k=1,..,d} \vert X_{n,k}-X_{0,k}\vert>\epsilon)\to 0$ also.

**2**. Assume $\max_{k=1,...,d}\vert X_{n,k}-X_{0,k}\vert \to^p 0$

Let $\epsilon>0$

Let $Y_n=\max_{k=1,...,d}\vert X_{n,k}-X_{0,k}\vert$

$\sum_{k=1}^d (X_{n,k}-X_{0,k})^2 \leq dY_n^2$

By continuous mapping, we know that since $Y_n\to^p 0$ then so does $dY_n^2\to^p 0$

And since $\sum_{k=1}^d (X_{n,k}-X_{0,k})^2 \leq dY_n^2$, $\lim_{n\to \infty} P(\vert \sum_{k=1}^d (X_{n,k}-X_{0,k})^2\vert>\epsilon)\leq \lim_{n\to \infty}P(dY_n^2>\epsilon)=0$ so by squeeze theorem  $P(\vert \sum_{k=1}^d (X_{n,k}-X_{0,k})^2\vert>\epsilon)=0$, as required.

**3**. Assume $\sum_{k=1}^d(X_{n,k}-X_{0,k})^2\to^p 0$

Since $\vert X_n-X_0\vert = \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^d(X_{n,k}-X_{0,k})^2}$

Since square root is continuous by continuous mapping theorem we get $\vert X_n - X_0\vert\to^p 0$

And since absolute value is continuous, we get $X_n-X_0\to^p 0$

Then $\lim_{n\to \infty} P(\vert X_n-X\vert>\epsilon =\lim_{n\to \infty} P(\vert X_n-X-0\vert>\epsilon=0$ so $X_n\to^p X$

**Is this correct?**

I think most of this is correct assuming I can treat distances between random vectors the same as regular vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, so I'm wondering if that is true. And also whether I did something in this proof which is not actually true for random variables.

Comment: 1 to 2 and 2 to 3 look alright, but how did you justify 3 to 1? The 2-norm (not absolute value) is a continuous function from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R$, but it doesn't have an inverse, and it seems as if you are saying its inverse is continuous when appealing to continuous mapping theorem.

Comment: @Golden_Ratio Yeah you are right that's a mistake. But I suppose instead I could say $P(\vert\vert X_n - X_0\vert \vert>\epsilon)=P(\vert X_n-X_0\vert >\epsilon)$ so I get that $X_n - X_0\to^p 0$ and the rest follows?

Comment: Yep, that's right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks alright to me (algebraic identities can indeed be applied to random vectors), except I'm not sure I follow your step from 3 to 1 as currently written; the 2-norm is a continuous map from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R$ but doesn't have an inverse map so I don't see how you would use the continuous mapping theorem (CMT) to move from $\|X_n-X\|_2\overset{p}{\rightarrow}0$ to $X_n\overset{p}{\rightarrow}X,$ where $\|\cdot\|_2$ is the 2-norm.

Fortunately, this step is salvageable by simply noting that

$$P(|\|X_n-X\|_2-0|>\epsilon)=P(\|X_n-X\|_2>\epsilon),$$

so it is clear that $\|X_n-X\|_2\overset{p}{\rightarrow}0\iff X_n\overset{p}{\rightarrow}X.$

---

I would like to point out that you can show a more general result than the ones you show, namely that $X_n\overset{p}{\rightarrow}X$ if and only if $\|X_n-X\|_p \overset{p}{\rightarrow}0$ for any $p$-norm $\|\cdot \|_p,p\geq 1.$ You essentially proved this for the cases $p=2$ and $p=\infty.$

You can prove this broader claim by showing that for any $p$-norm,
$$X_{n,k} \overset{p}{\rightarrow}X_k,\forall k\in\{1,...,d\}\iff \|X_n-X\|_p \overset{p}{\rightarrow}0.$$

Comment: Pls upvote if you find it helpful!